# How LLVM/Clang implements RVO

Tags: llvm, rvo

I am trying to figure out how LLVM implements RVO. The simplest idea for me was to have pointer in arguments and memcpy to it any value that needs to be returned from a function. Then run `memcpyopt` pass and get RVO this way if possible.

It seems that's what happening, with -fno-elide-constructors:

```
define void @_Z3fooic(%struct.X* noalias sret, i32, i8 signext) #0 {
    ..
    call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %12, i8* %13, i64 20, i32 4, i1 false)
    ret void
```

and without it seems that all the operations are directly applied to `%0`.

Is that correct understanding or am I missing some caveats here?

**EDIT**

```
define i8 @make_positive_point_x_I64_y_I64(i64 %x, i64 %y, %Point*) {
entry:
  %1 = or i64 %x, %y
  %2 = icmp slt i64 %1, 0
  br i1 %2, label %exit, label %merge

merge:                                            ; preds = %entry
  %3 = alloca %Point, align 8
  call void @"Point___new_self_&Point_x_I64_y_I64"(%Point* nonnull %3, i64 %x, i64 %y)
  %4 = bitcast %Point* %0 to i8*
  %5 = bitcast %Point* %3 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %4, i8* %5, i64 zext (%Point* inttoptr (i64 16 to %Point*) to i64), i32 1, i1 false)
  br label %exit

exit:                                             ; preds = %entry, %merge
  %.0 = phi i8 [ 0, %merge ], [ 1, %entry ]
  ret i8 %.0
}
```

It seems `memcpyopt` is not sufficient, as it doesn't recognize that it can use `%0` instead of `%3`.